# How to get params value from url using angular8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular9

Trying to get the value from the url using ActivatedRoute.
I am passing id value from dashboard component and trying to get that value from main component.
But not able to get the value. If anyone know please help to find the solution.

dashboard.component.ts:

```
  nextComp(){
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'],  { queryParams: {id:'2'}}); 
  }
```

main.component.ts:

```
    ngAfterViewInit(){ 
       this.route.params.subscribe((param : Params) => {
           alert( param['id'] ); 
     });
    }
```

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-feature-modules-final-example-sdecfy?file=app%2Fdashboard%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

instead of using params you must have to use queryParams, like this :

```
   ngAfterViewInit(){ 
       this.route.queryParams.subscribe((param : Params) => {
           alert( param['id'] ); 
     });
    }
```

Comment: You need to clarify the why. `params` are for route params ex: "accounts/:accountId".